# Expand a treeViewItem Automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, treeview

I have a TreeView that I filled with a list of TreeViewItem from a collection (using the binding), I linked to a TreeView event "Expand" to expand it and display their childrens, my objective now is to get the last TreeViewItem accessed and to initialize the TreeView by the  last treeViewItem consulted.
I can retrieve the last TreeViewItem consulted and their childrens, but I can not expand it automatically. I use this method, but it returns always null.

> TreeViewItem item =control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lastItem)as TreeViewItem;
>    item.IsExpanded = true;
>
> item is always null, isExpanded doses not work, and lastItem is a string(the text you see on the screen : is the treeViewItem.datacontext recovred ).

Comment: You should specify it's the `System.Windows.Controls.TreeView` (WPF) version of `TreeView`.

Comment: firstly thank you for your answer, 
But where I should specify the version

Answer (score 2):

You should read [this CodeProject article on TreeView MVVM approach](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) which will simplify all your work with TreeView and TreeViewItem controls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Expand Subtree method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expandsubtree.aspx) for TreeViewItem class?

The ExpandSubtree() method:

> Expands the TreeViewItem control and all its child TreeViewItem elements.

Example:

```
TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewitem();
item.ExpandSubtree();
```